# Limiting docker logging

Tags: logging, docker

I have an application that runs user code. I'd like to make sure Docker is not collecting too many logs which I'll anyway discard. For this, I'm trying to use `max-size` and `max-file` logging options to get just the **last** few kilobytes of the user output and discard the rest, but that does not seem to work.

If I do:

```
$ docker run --log-opt max-size=2 --log-opt max-file=1 python:2 python -c "for i in range(10): print i"
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Then it still prints the full output on the screen. If I examine the logs manually on the host, I can see the files with the full output are there.

Shouldn't I be getting only `9\n` in this case? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The options you are using are for max file size and number of files. Max size sud be k/m/g. Even after setting that you won't be able to predict exact number of lines. It's by file size

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dockers [JSON file log options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/#json-file-options) won't impact the stdout and stderr  streamed to your `docker` client. You will see the complete output when running in the foreground.

When you run [`docker logs`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/), information will be pulled back from file.

The maximum size requires a unit. kilobytes, megabytes or gigabytes.

```
--log-opt max-size=[0-9+][k|m|g]
```

This sets the size of a JSON log file so there is extra metadata compared to just the line length that contributes to the size.

```
{"log":"1\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2016-05-30T07:39:31.265191929Z"}
```

You should fit a maximum of 14 log entries into 1k of space. Whether dockers log rotation is that accurate or not is another matter.

You are probably wasting time dealing with file sizes less than 4k in any case.

Comment: I agree the example is a bit contrived (we don't intend to keep only 2 bytes of output ;-). What you say seems to work, except that it is not the last N[k|m|g] bytes which are saved. The logs are rolled over and **at most** N[k|m|g] bytes are saved from the user output. I.e., it is not implemented as a circular buffer with a FIFO. This could be a bit better explained in the docs.

Comment: That's a pretty standard setup for file logging in unix. Circular file buffers would be rare as it's not provided by standard linux file systems. The kernel can do small in memory buffers. You might want to try the [journald logger](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/journald/) as that can log to a ring buffer without you having to set anything up.